# EPEL repository for ARM7

Tags: centos7, armv7, banana-pi, epel

Trying to setup a banana-pi with CentOS 7 to be used a NAS, I come across many packages I have to compile myself.

I wonder if there is a special repo for the armv7 architecture ?

```
%uname -a
Linux bananapi 4.2.3-200.el7.armv7hl #1 SMP Wed Nov 25 18:01:51 EST 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this moment are not available. But they are working on it
https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/arm-dev/2015-May/000184.html

Comment: Great, thanks for that link. So I'll either have to wait or volunteer.

Answer (score 14):

I was trying to install Python3 on my RPi3 running CentOS 7.  I attempted installing from the EPEL repository ( `sudo yum install epel-release` &&  `sudo yum install python34`).  This failed, but after some digging around I found that the CentOS wiki has a nice section for 32 bit arm.

I followed the instructions (which are at the very bottom of the wiki), and after that I was able to install an **automatically generated, unsigned and untested working version of EPEL 7.** I haven't found mentions of this on SO, so I hope that it helps.

> [**How can I enable EPEL 7 on armhfp ?**](https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/AltArch/Arm32#head-f2a772703b3caa90cc284e01bc87423ce9a87bcd)
>
> The answer is easy in a sense that there is no official EPEL repository for armfhp. But because lot of users were asking for this, we decided to use the centos armhfp builders to (re)build Source packages from EPEL 7 (and try to track those automatically) when they're idle. Please note that it's just an automatic rebuild without any QA/test, and also resulting pkgs aren't signed either. To use that repository, proceed like this :

```
cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo << EOF
[epel]
name=Epel rebuild for armhfp
baseurl=https://armv7.dev.centos.org/repodir/epel-pass-1/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

EOF
```

After that, running `sudo yum install epel-release` succeeded, as did installing Python3.

Comment: Thank you! This is *exactly* what I was looking for!

Comment: Perfect! Needed this to install pi-hole on my Raspberry Pi 3 with CentOS 7, and it kept silently failing the install process. Worked great. Thanks!

Comment: So simple but exactly what I needed. Hopefully this helps more people until EPEL is available for armhfv7